# My template class returns the wrong data

Tags: c++, templates

So when I run the program I wrote below what prints out is

```
What is passed in 4 7
What is inside -1138187264 32566
-1138187264 + 32566 = -1138154698
1
0
```

I need it to hold 4 and 7 instead of the garbage numbers it currently holds. I don't think I passed my values in incorrectly. I tried to dereference them but that didnt work either. I just want my class calculator to hold 2 int numbers. But for some reason when I pass in the numbers it doesn't recognize them? I'm not too sure what is happening here.

This is the main class I have

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Calculator.h"
#include "Calculator.cpp"
using namespace std;

class Arithmetic {
private:
    int intData;
public:
    Arithmetic() {
        intData = 0;
    }
    Arithmetic(int i) {
        intData = i;
    }
    void intOperations(Arithmetic obj) {
        cout << "What is passed in " << intData << " " << obj.intData << endl;
        Calculator<int> cint(intData, obj.intData);
        cout << "What is inside " << cint.getValue1() << " " << cint.getValue2() << endl;
        printOperations(cint);
    }
};

int main(){
    // Create 1st object
    int int1 = 4;
    Arithmetic arith1(int1);
    // Create 2nd object
    int int2 = 7;
    Arithmetic arith2(int2);
    arith1.intOperations(arith2);

}
```

This is my calc.h header

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H

template <class T>
class Calculator {
private:
    T value1;
    T value2;
public:
    Calculator();
    Calculator(T value1, T value2);
    T getValue1();
    T getValue2();
    T getSum();
    int getLogicalAND();
    bool isGreater();
};

#endif
```

This is my calc.cpp class

```
#include "calc.h"
template <class T>
Calculator<T>::Calculator(){
    value1 = T();
    value2 = T();
}

template <class T>
Calculator<T>::Calculator(T value1, T value2) {
    value1 = value1;
    value2 = value2;
}

template <class T>
T Calculator<T>::getValue1() {
    return value1;
}

template <class T>
T Calculator<T>::getValue2() {
    return value2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
template <class T>
Calculator<T>::Calculator(T value1, T value2) {
    value1 = value1;
    value2 = value2;
}
```

You're mixing function parameters and class attributes....after compiler optimization (because when you write `value1 = value1;`....you are doing nothing actually...), you end up with something equivalent to:

```
template <class T>
Calculator<T>::Calculator(T value1, T value2) {
}
```

So `value1` and `value2` are uninitialized...it's garbage.

You need to do:

```
template <class T>
Calculator<T>::Calculator(T value1, T value2) {
    this->value1 = value1;
    this->value2 = value2;
}
```

Even better, use initialization list:

```
template <class T>
Calculator<T>::Calculator(T value1, T value2) : 
    value1(value1), 
    value2(value2) 
{
}
```

Comment: I did not know I had the keyword "this" in C++. I tried what you wrote but it still not working I am still getting garbage returns.

Comment: No way, add `std::cout << value1 << " " << this->value1 << std::cout` within the function to check what's going on.

Comment: @isignisign: Checked the edit, end of my post. There's another issue in your code

Comment: It seems that my make wasnt recompiling the code correctly? It didnt detect the change in Caculator.cpp. After running make clean the problem went away thank you!

Comment: @isignisign: Yes, my mistake, your class is copiable as default copy constructor will work with simple `int` attributes. Please vote up and accept the answer if this fixed your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
template <class T>
Calculator<T>::Calculator(T value1, T value2) {
    value1 = value1;
    value2 = value2;
}
```

is not doing what you think it does. You should at least write :

```
this->value1 = value1;
```

or even better give the parameter a different name.

Comment: That's really, really close to my answer, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: This still does not fix the problem. I tried both of jpo378's methods.

Comment: @jpo38 yep, you were just faster. Not really surprising, as this is obviously wrong in OPs code ;)

Comment: @isignisign I dont see any other problem. Are you sure you made a fresh clean build?